# SSRS Report shows data for different dates

Tags: sql, date, reporting-services, group-by, aggregate

My report(which calculates attendance %) shows aggregated data if I remove the sessiondate field.

But I need it as users need to run it each month(currently we run query manually)

So, I have sessiondate field in my query which is based on start and end date parameters

**Query:**

```
SELECT sessiondate,
       Possible,
       Present,
       SUM(Possible_Duration)                      AS Possible_Duration,
       SUM(Present_Duration)                       AS Present_Duration,
       CASE WHEN SUM(Present_Duration) = 0 THEN 0
       ELSE
         SUM(Present_Duration) / SUM(Possible_Duration) END AS Attendance,
       SUM(CASE WHEN Mark = 'L' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS Late_Mark,
       SUM(Possible)                               AS Possib,
       SUM(CASE WHEN Mark = 'A' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS Authorised_absence,
       SUM(CASE WHEN Mark = '/' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS Present_,
       SUM(CASE WHEN Mark = 'O' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS Absent_fromClass
  FROM Table
 WHERE Sessiondate >= @startdate
   AND Sessiondate <= @Enddate
 GROUP BY Session_dt
```

**Query result:**

```
--------------------------------------
 col1 | col2 | Session_dt | attendance 
--------------------------------------
   A  |   B  | 01/01/2015 |     100
   A  |   B  | 03/01/2015 |      69
   A  |   B  | 05/01/2015 |     100
```

**Expected result:**

```
--------------------------
 col1 | col2 | attendance 
--------------------------
   A  |  B   |     89.3
```

For now I just specified dates in my query and running the report. Is there any way I can achieve this using parameter values?

Comment: Where does `attendance %` comes from in Data? I see no Select on attendance.

Comment: Invalid GROUP BY... The general rule is: "If a GROUP BY clause is specified, each column reference in the SELECT list must either identify a grouping column or be the argument of a set function."

Answer (score 0):

This query will return data between first and last date of the current month, then you only need to schedule your report to run every month end or something:

```
select *
where [Date] between
CONVERT(VARCHAR(25),DATEADD(dd,-(DAY(GETDATE())-1),GETDATE()),101) --first date
and 
CONVERT(VARCHAR(25),DATEADD(dd,-(DAY(DATEADD(mm,1,GETDATE()))),DATEADD(mm,1,GETDATE())),101) --last date
```

Comment: Yingy, any idea how can I run this for previous month at present it shows as 01 Feb - 29 Feb

Answer (score 0):

You can put one parameter on your SSRS report as @monthNo and simply display the month list of Jan - Dec with simply value of 1 -12.

On SQL side, you could receive month number that the user selected and use it like this:

```
declare @monthNo as char(2) = '1'; -- remove this from your SQL

declare @firstDate as datetime;
declare @lastDate as datetime;


select  @firstDate = CONVERT(datetime,CONVERT(CHAR(4),year(getdate())) + '-' + @monthNo + '-1');
select  @lastDate = dateadd(day,-1,(dateadd(month,1,@firstDate)));

select *
from [table]
where [date] between @firstDate and @lastDate;
```

Now you can run the report for whatever month.